# dynamic memory allocation for array of structures

Tags: c++

I want to dynamically allocate for an array of structure 'student'`

```
struct student
     { 
     char* name;
};
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   if(argc==2)
   {
     student* sptr=new student[4]; 
     for(int i=0;i<atoi(argv[1]);i++)
     {
         cin>>*(*(sptr+i)).name;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<atoi(argv[1]);i++)
     {
         cout<<*(*(sptr+i)).name;
     }
   }
}
```

the code is compiling without error,but at runtime, after entering first name is
says "segmentation fault(core dumped)" and halts.where i am going wrong?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `name`. Use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: Just because you have a pointer doesn't mean you must use pointer arithmetic and dereference. For any array *or pointer* `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`. So instead of doing `*(sptr+i)` in your loop, just do `sptr[i]`.

Comment: Also, are you supposed to read and print only a *single character*? Because that what you will be doing when you dereference the (***uninitialized!***) pointer `name` in the input/output.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No I need to take a name eg:"Mikhil" as input.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need a struct to hold only one string
2. You don't need to call `atoi` in each iteration
3. You need to allocate memory in order to receive user input

A working code could be as following:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    // Exit if wrong number of arguments
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect number of argements";
        return 1;
    }

    // Convert argument from ASCII to int once
    int numberOfValues = atoi(argv[1]);
    // Create array of strings (pointer of pointers to characters)
    char** ppValues = new char*[numberOfValues];

    // Loop to collect strings
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
    {
        // Local variable to collect one string
        char buffer[1024];
        cin >> buffer;
        // Allocate memory in one of the array entries to hold the current entry
        ppValues[i] = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
        // Copy value from temp string to final string location
        strcpy(ppValues[i], buffer);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
    {
        cout << ppValues[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a seg fault because you are trying to access uninitialized memory (the pointer `name` is never initialized) as pointed out by πάντα ῥεῖ and Joachim Pileborg.

Using std::string is the way to go; however, if this is an exercise or for whatever reason you should be using a char *, then it needs to be initialized for each of the array item separately in a loop.

```
student* sptr=new student[4]; 
for(int i=0;i<atoi(argv[1]);i++)
{
    sptr[i].name = new char[10]; // now name is properly initialized and can hold a string of length (10 - 1)
    cin >> sptr[i].name;
}
```

And when printing out the string, you should be doing

`cout << sptr[i].name;`

This is the same as `(*(sptr+i)).name`. This gives the `char *` that holds the string, if you add another  `*` in front of the expression than it dereferences the pointer and gives you the first character of the string. So if you were to print only the first character, then your expression is just fine. However, to print out the whole string you should not dereference the pointer by adding another `*` to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a segmentation because your program has **undefined behaviour**. There is an error in your code which your compiler is not required to diagnose; it instead generates a binary which can do anything, including random crashes.

Depending on user input, your problems are starting with the use of `atoi` in this line:

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<atoi(argv[1]);i++)
> ```

First of all, your program can obviously only work if the user enters "4", which makes me wonder why you need user input anyway. Chances are that you wanted to write `new student[atoi(argv[1]]` in the line above.

Nevertheless, `atoi` is a dangerous function and should almost never be used. As [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) says:

> If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return
>   type, the return value is undefined.

Which means that you will never know if the user entered a harmless number like "1" or something like "10000000000000000000000000", which is probably larger than the maximum `int` value on your machine.

What's possibly worse:

> If no conversion can be performed, ​`0`​ is returned.

Which means you will never know if the user entered "abc" or "0".

[`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is a safe, modern alternative which allows you to perform error checking.

Still, let's assume that the user simply enters a "4".

We then enter into the loop body and encounter the following line:

> ```
> cin>>*(*(sptr+i)).name;
> ```

Readability issues aside, what's happening here is:

- `i` is still 0, so you get `(sptr+0)`, which is equal to `(sptr)`.
- `sptr` is dereferenced to obtain a reference to a `student` object.
- You try to dereference the `name` pointer of the `student` object.

The latter step finally results in undefined behaviour, because the `name` pointer was **not initialised**. You must not do this. All the rest of your program has been rendered invalid at this point.

Getting this right with bare pointers is extremely difficult. You could add user input asking for the size of each name, so that you can allocate enough memory before reading the name. Or you could employ an even more complex approach using [low-level member functions of `std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

Fortunately, you don't have to do any of this. This is C++: use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). **Use C++ and not C** if you want to write C++ and not C, and all your problems will disappear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

struct student
{ 
    std::string name;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   try
   {
       if (argc == 2)
       {
           std::vector<student> students(std::stoi(argv[1]));
           for (auto&& student : students)
           {
               std::getline(std::cin, student.name);
           }

           for (auto&& student : students)
           {
               std::cout << student.name << "\n";
           }
       }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

This program has defined behaviour; it will not crash with wrong input, and it will allow names with spaces in them. It is also easier to read, does not use any pointers on the outside, and it handles memory automatically, smarter and faster than manual code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Explanation.

Answer (score 0):

segment fault is you are accessing a memory location without initialize it. You need not to define a struct. Since it is CPP, so why not try CPP `std::string` data type.

And the `name` attribute in `student` struct is never allocated memory in your code.

try:

```
string * st = new string[atoi(argv[1])];
for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i ++)
{
    cin >> st[i];
    cout << st[i] << endl;
}
```

or

```
std::vector<std::string> name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store names from input, you just need to use a data structure like vector or list of strings to avoid errors like memory managment:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
// std::list<std::string> names;
```